# MVC Implementation using Zend Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I am currently working on a login system for a site using the Zend Framework for its MVC architecture.

Which design makes more sense

- registration and login each gets its own set of model, views and controllers.
- both the registration and login is implemented within the same model, view and controller.

Would love to hear the arguments for and against both design patterns so i can better understand the "preferred" or "best" way to implement a program using the MVC architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think separate `controllers` and `views` should be used for **Login(Authentication)** and **Registration** but same database `Model`, `DbTable` and `Mapper` classes can be used for both.

**For Example:**

**Login Controller:**

```
index action (Show login form)
process action (Process login form)
```

*Access URL: projectname.com/login*

**Registration Controller:**

```
index action (Show registration form)
process action (Process registration form)
```

*Access URL: projectname.com/registration*

**BUT same:**

```
Model class
Mapper class
DbTable class
```

Comment: What exactly does the mapper class do? So far, i have completed the registration portion of the code, and did not use this Mapper class. The Zend documentation isn't very clear about it as well.

Comment: Please review the tutorial here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html

Comment: Mapper class is used to contact with database. It contains functions like `find()`, `save()`, and `fetchAll()`.

Comment: Thank you, that is a great help indeed.